2D tile map game: Calculate room tiles a furniture item was placed at
I'm developing for a 2D tile map game. I'm trying to generate a list of tiles a furniture item has been placed at, also supporting multi tile furniture that cover more than one tile.
I've written a calculation method to fetch the relevant tiles based on some info like the X, Y, width and length as well as the direction / orientation.
Direction can be 0 - 7, obviously 1 3, 5 and 7 are off bounds as their diagonal.
See:
public enum Direction
{
    North = 0,
    NorthEast = 1,
    East = 2,
    SouthEast = 3,
    South = 4,
    SouthWest = 5,
    West = 6,
    NorthWest = 7
}

Here is the calculation method:
public List<RoomTile?> GetTileCollection(
    int x, 
    int y, 
    int width, 
    int length, 
    int direction)
{
    var tiles = new List<RoomTile>();
    
    if (direction is 0 or 4)
    {
        for (var i = x; i <= (x + (width - 1)); i++)
        {
            for (var j = y; j <= (y + (length - 1)); j++)
            {
                var t = FindTile(i, j);

                if (t == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                
                tiles.Add(t);
            }
        }
    }
    else if (direction is 2 or 6)
    {
        for (var i = x; i <= (x + (length - 1)); i++)
        {
            for (var j = y; j <= (y + (width - 1)); j++)
            {
                var t = FindTile(i, j);

                if (t == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                
                tiles.Add(t);
            }
        }
    }

    return tiles;
}

A room tile is:
public class RoomTile(int x, int y, float z, RoomTileState state, List<RoomFurnitureItem> items)
{
    public HPoint Point { get; } = new(x, y, z);
    public RoomTileState State { get; } = state;
    public List<RoomFurnitureItem> Items { get; } = items;
    public Dictionary<long, IRoomUser> Users { get; } = [];
}


Does the code work? If so, please remove the question from the title. How is GetTileCollection called?

Yes it works, I'm looking for optimizations. GetTileCollection gets called inside an event handler which is triggered upon placing a furniture item. It just passes the coords and gets back a collection of tiles that furniture item covers.

The "big 4" directions are typically called Cardinal directions. The next 4 are "intercardinal" directions, sometimes called Ordinal directions. I suggest you create a separate enum type for cardinals, and whatever supporting code you need. Then you can pass an enum value that you will completely cover. Alternatively, you might call it Orientation. Still, C# loves exhaustive switch statements, so it's worth tuning the type to the actual range of values you expect.
Your code differs in the two cases by how the loops are limited. I suggest you make this explicit, and unify the two cases otherwise:
int i_limit = width; 
int j_limit = height;

switch (orientation) {
case Cardinal.East: 
case Cardinal.West:
    i_limit = height; // change how i,j are limited
    j_limit = width;
    break;
default: break;
}

for (var i = x; i < x + i_limit; ++i)
    for (var j = y; j < y + j_limit; ++j) {
        var t = FindTile(...);
        // etc.
    }

Next, consider using the Null Object pattern for your tile searches. In a 2d game, there is always a lot of code written for checking that x,y values are not out-of-range. Instead of checking this over and over again, just implement your bottom-level accessors to return Null Object tiles whenever an out-of-bounds value is requested. This will allow you to write your code assuming that all the indexes are valid:
Tile FindTile(int x, int y) {
    if (0 <= x && x < MAX_X && 0 <= y && y < MAX_Y)
        return tiles[x][y];
    else
        return Global_null_tile;
}

If your Tile objects are mutable, as they appear to be, then you'll want to create a separate type for the Null tile, since that tile needs to either quietly succeed with no changes, or quietly fail, depending on the method. (A "store treasure at tile" could succeed and do nothing, dropping the treasure into the void. But a "move player to tile" operation must fail, since players cannot step off the map. You'll have to think carefully about all this stuff.)
